# Coldfusion check if function exists

Tags: function, coldfusion

Hello is there a way to check if a function exists in coldfusion. It is throwing an error function is not defined

Comment: Are you talking about a ColdFusion built-in function, are you talking about a UDF or are you talking about a method of a CFC? You should not call a function in your code if it does not exist.

Comment: .. which is why we need to see code and the error message. *Normally* (though not always) what you describe should not occur. If so, it is better to find out the cause and fix it, rather than applying a band-aid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `isDefined('functionname')` works. So you can do:

```
<cfif isDefined('functionname')>
    <cfset functionname() />
</cfif>
```

If it's a potential method of an object named `obj` for example you can also do:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(obj,'functionname')>
  <cfset obj.functionname() />
</cfif>
```

Or

```
<cfif isDefined('obj.functionname')>
  <cfset obj.functionname() />
</cfif>
```

Comment: The above code checks for the existence of specified variable name (not specifically function) in different scopes. You can't be sure if the function of the specified name exists on the basis of it. If there is a variable with same name as the function (you are checking for) in other scopes, the above trick will fail. So be cautious.

Comment: That is true, but if you are writing code where you are sharing variable names with function names and also needing to test the existence of them, good luck to you. Thanks for clarifying that. All this simply does it test for the existence of an item with that name. It could be a function, object, query or any other type.

Comment: And if the object is not instantiated yet, one can use GetComponentMetadata providing path to the component, e.g.:
    `methods = GetComponentMetadata('testCfc').functions;
    WriteDump(YesNoFormat(ArrayFind(methods, function (f) {return f.name eq 'testFunction';})));`

Comment: Would isCustomFunction() work as way to determine if something is a function? https://cfdocs.org/iscustomfunction  To better determine, I wrote a TypeOf UDF to attempt to identify the type of any CF object. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/1ed396431dfb8e0e9f58

Comment: No,  isCustomFunction( myFunct ) will throw an error if myFunct is undefined.